# Split "map" into gps coordinate grid by certain kilometer number

Tags: math, geolocation, geometry, maps, coordinates

So I have a odd problem, which I can't really wrap my head around how to fix, mostly because I'm not that good at math I guess :-)

So lets say we have a map, any map, which has four corners, obviously. And this is a real-world map. And I would like to get every coordinate, by let's say a 15 kilometer interval on the entire map. How would I go about the math for that? Or is there a tool that can do this perhaps?

And we're talking long's and lat's here, not sure if that is important. And I don't really care about being precise, if it there is less than 2km error in the coordinates then I'm fine. I don't know if that makes it easier.

I did a shitty drawing to help explain, https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJZlO.jpg
I am talking about all the "solid squares" those are the coordinates I would like, for an entire country as an example.

I'm hoping this problem will make sense, and someone can help me out here :-)

Comment: the certain kilometer number your looking for depends greatly on the map scale, (e.g. on a 1:50,000 scale map a "square" could be 1x1 in kilometers on the actual terrain),  from that you can pretty much infer most of what you need by simple math, so.. what's the scale of the map? and the radius you want (which would be the distance from the center of the, let's say "starting point")?

Comment: I see.. That seems strange to me, as I just want every 15 kilometer of a country mapped in every direction.. If that makes sense? I don't really care about scale, as I am not interested in the visual representation? Please let me know if I am not making sense :-)

Comment: Sorry but long's and lat's are in degrees (angles) and that can't be (directly) measured to linear distances. I'm a little confused what you have at hand. All maps you have have the longitudes and latitudes? If so, you can calculate the point for ever 15km marker.